# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"html")

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, jaxb, unmarshalling

I get the following exception when I try to get object from my web service:

```java
 javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"html"). Expected elements are <{}user>
```

User class is annotated with `@XmlRootElement`, accessing the web service through browser displays xml representation of user

Client code (I use `MediaType.TEXT_HTML` because `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML` cause `RestClientException`):

```java
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter jaxbMessageConverter = new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter();
List<MediaType> mediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
mediaTypes.add(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
jaxbMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediaTypes);
messageConverters.add(jaxbMessageConverter);
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
User x = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/Online_Shopping/dispatcher/rest/hello",User.class);
```

**Web Service code:**

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest")
public class RESTController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", 
    method = RequestMethod.GET, 
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody User getUser() {
      return new  User("paymon","123",true); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about the RestClientException you are getting with application/xml? I notice you are not passing Accept header. So if you are getting a 406 Not Acceptable; absence of Accept header is the reason

Comment: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.shopping.model.User] and content type [text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1]

Comment: Paymon, Can you make sure that you add this: `mediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE);` in your RestTemplate code and give me the RestClientException you get now?

Comment: I added that code, I get the same exception  javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"html").  I set the header to application/xml through a custom interceptor.

Comment: I commented out the security interceptor and it works now. Now I am just wondering how to secure the web service because I can only access it (through browser) when I am logged in. But when I am logged in I cannot access the web service through java code.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't have access to the web service because of a security interceptor.  `<intercept-url pattern="/dispatcher/rest/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>` After commenting out the interceptor my web service works properly.  Only problem is I am wondering how to secure my web service to access it through java code.